Scroll animation is not working properly [CSS]
I was trying to create an infinite scroll animation with smooth transition.


.container-contribution {
  width: 45%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.container-loop {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  gap: 2%;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #111 20%, #fff 80%, transparent);
}

.container-loop img {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 350px;
  width: auto;
}

.infoCtb {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 40%;
  animation: loop 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loop {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    /* Safari & Chrome */
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-400%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-400%);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-400%);
    /* Safari & Chrome */
  }
}
<div class="container-contribution">
  <h2>Contributors</h2>
  <div class="container-loop">
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/ChrisHadfield.jpg" alt="ChrisHadfield">
      <span>Chris Hadfield</span>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/GuionBluford.jpg" alt="GuionBluford">
      <span>Guion Bluford</span>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/JeremySchnittman.jpg" alt="JeremySchnittman">
      <span>Jeremy Schnittman</span>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/MichelleThaller.jpg" alt="MichelleThaller">
      <span>Michelle Thaller</span>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/NeildeGrasse.jpg" alt="NeildeGrasse">
      <span>Neil deGrasse</span>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/NASA.jpg" alt="NASA">
    </div>
    <!-- Duplicate content for smooth looping -->
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/ChrisHadfield.jpg" alt="ChrisHadfield">
      <span>Chris Hadfield</span>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/GuionBluford.jpg" alt="GuionBluford">
      <span>Guion Bluford</span>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/JeremySchnittman.jpg" alt="JeremySchnittman">
      <span>Jeremy Schnittman</span>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/MichelleThaller.jpg" alt="MichelleThaller">
      <span>Michelle Thaller</span>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/NeildeGrasse.jpg" alt="NeildeGrasse">
      <span>Neil deGrasse</span>
    </div>
    <div class="infoCtb">
      <img src="images/NASA.jpg" alt="NASA">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I found in several articles that duplicating the elements will hide the moment when it will start again. However when I try to run it, it is visible and I can't find a way to solve it.

So it happens you can set each flexed child to be exactly 50% of its parent. Or any other percent for that matter.
/* Each child div takes up exactly 50% of the parent width */
flex: 0 0 50%;

So knowing that, we can conclude that after exactly 600% of translateX, the 6 images would complete a lap. I removed the gaps to make it precise. If you still want a margin, you can use the padding each image container, .infoCtb


var html = document.querySelector(".container-loop").innerHTML
document.querySelector(".container-loop").innerHTML = html + html
.container-contribution {
  width: 45%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.container-loop {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  gap: 0;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #111 20%, #fff 80%, transparent);
}

.infoCtb {
  /* Each child div takes up exactly 50% of the parent width */
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  animation: loop 5s linear infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 2px;
}

.infoCtb span,
.infoCtb img {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

@keyframes loop {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-600%);
  }
}
<div class="container-contribution">
  <h2>Contributors</h2>
  <div class="container-loop">
    <div class="infoCtb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/111/150/90/" alt="ChrisHadfield"><span>Chris Hadfield</span></div>
    <div class="infoCtb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/112/150/90/" alt="GuionBluford"><span>Guion Bluford</span></div>
    <div class="infoCtb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/113/150/90/" alt="JeremySchnittman"><span>Jeremy Schnittman</span></div>
    <div class="infoCtb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/114/150/90/" alt="MichelleThaller"><span>Michelle Thaller</span></div>
    <div class="infoCtb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/115/150/90/" alt="NeildeGrasse"><span>Neil deGrasse</span></div>
    <div class="infoCtb"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/116/150/90/" alt="NASA"></div>
  </div>
</div>



